# Batch file for/f doesn't work with all after construction

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say I have a simple batch file:

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ("f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7") do echo %%a
```

I'm trying to print out `f3 f4 f5 f6 f7` but all I get is `f3`

What's wrong with my batch file?

Comment: `%1 to %9`, and `%0` are used as batch file parameters and it is unwise to use `%%1` as a loop variable.  The documented letters are `a-z` and `A-Z` and they are normally adequate for any loop variable.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is actually simpler.

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ("f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7") do echo %%b
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple. You just need to add `%%a`. Now batch file should looks like this:

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ("f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7") do echo %%a %%b
```

Where `%%a` - stands for third token `%%b` - stands for all tokens after third token.